# Activity/ViewModel recreated when new Activity is shown

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I have Activity A, which displays a list of items that are loaded asynchronously from a web service.  This list is stored in a ViewModel.  When you select one of those items Activity B will open up with details of the selected item.  Activity B is a child Activity of Activity A.  Pressing the back button will then go back to Activity A...however, at this point Activity A is destroyed and a new ViewModel is created which calls the web service again.

This isn't similar to the other issues I have seen where the device is rotated while Activity B is in the foreground.  The onDestroy method of Activity A is not called when the item is selected and Activity B is displayed...but it is called when the back button is pressed.

I don't want the ViewModel to refresh the data every time the user goes back to Activity A...any idea what could be causing this?

Relevant Manifest info:

```
    <activity android:name=".ActivityA" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityB"
        android:label="@string/title_b"
        android:parentActivityName=".ActivityA" />
```

Activity A:

```
class ActivityA : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.a_activity)
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        ...
```

Not sure what other code would help to diagnose the problem....

Comment: It's probably because you have `android:parentActivityName=".ActivityA"` in manifest for activity B. It tells the OS which activity to (re)start when going back up. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#parent Do you really need that? `parentActivityName` is used for up navigation. See relevant discussion: https://old.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ahg4zi/a_long_shot_but_activity_relaunches_when_back/

Comment: That was it...I was using that to handle the android.R.id.home press...but I have now removed it, and handled the android.R.id.home manually, seems to be working, thanks!   If you want to put your comment as and answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `android:parentActivityName=".ActivityA"` in your manifest. As stated in [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#parent):

> The system reads this attribute to determine which activity should be
> started when the user presses the Up button in the action bar.

Therefore, when you return to the previous activity, new `ViewModel` is created.